# Convert values in CSV column to individual columns

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file with the following format:

```
ID | STUFF |  Custom | Custom Value
1  | string1 | name1 | val1
1  | string1 | name2 | val2
1  | string1 | name3 | val3
2  | string2 | name1 | val4
2  | string2 | name3 | val5
3  | string3 | name2 | val6
```

etc...

The import part about the CSV is that the current Custom Column has various "Fields" in it that I need moved out to it's own column and paired with it's value in the next column.  The Custom column contains somewhat unknown values.  each ID, for example, may have a different subset of Custom "names".  I do, however, know the complete set of possible "Custom" names available.

Desired output: (NOTE:  I realized I goofed on what I needed for the output, so now it's corrected)

```
ID | STUFF    | name1       | name2      | name3

1  | SomeText | name1_Value | name2_Value| name3_Value
2  | SomeText | name1_Value | name2_Value| name3_Value
```

I am relatively new at Python and am having trouble seeing an elegant way of doing this without a serious amt of iterations/looping.  I figured that using the CSV module and DictReader with tuples will probably end up being the right way of going about this, but I'm strugging with it at the moment.  I have roughly 1200 rows in this file, and it only needs to work once, but I'd like to learn the best way to do things in python.

Comment: The names/vars of your output do not correspond to those defined in  your input. e.g. what CN2_Value is ?

Comment: I updated above to slightly clarify.  CNx_Value was just a place holder for whatever value was found for the associated field name.  ie:  name1:val1 = Cutsom_Name1:CN1_Value  (CN= Custom Name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this (assumes the rows in the csv are sorted by id):

```
import csv, itertools, operator
with open('data.csv', 'rb') as infile:
    results = []
    # uses the header row to get field names, each row will be a dict
    rows = csv.DictReader(infile)
    # keeps track of all the custom names we've seen
    all_custom_vals = set()
    for id_val, group in itertools.groupby(rows, operator.itemgetter('ID')):
        collapsed_row = {}
        for row in group:
            collapsed_row['ID'] = row['ID']
            collapsed_row['STUFF'] = row['STUFF']
            collapsed_row[row['Custom']] = row['Custom Value']
            all_custom_vals.add(row['Custom'])
        results.append(collapsed_row)
```

[`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) is really handy in situations like this.
Then `results` will be a list of dictionaries, which you can write out as csv using something like this:

```
import sys
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
keys = sorted(all_custom_vals)
writer.writerow(['ID', 'STUFF'] + keys)
for row in results:
    items = [row['ID'], row['STUFF']]
    for key in keys:
        items.append(row.get(key, '<no value>'))
    writer.writerow(items)
```

Replace `<no value>` with whatever the value should be when there was no row with that custom name.

Edit: actually, the output I've given isn't quite what you asked for (although I think it might be more useful). To get exactly what you asked for, you'd change the second part to be:

```
import sys
writer = csv.writer(sys.stdout)
keys = sorted(all_custom_vals)
for row in results:
    items = [row['ID'], row['STUFF']]
    for key in keys:
        items.append(key)
        items.append(row.get(key, '<no value>'))
    writer.writerow(items)
```

Comment: This works very well.  I made some tweaks to handle some other weird things in the CSV I have, but it's fairly simple to understand.   I did make a mistake in my original question regarding the desired output, so I'm going to go through what I have and see if I can correct it.  If so, I'll post up what I did.

Comment: The first solution actually gave me what I wanted, not what I asked for initially haha!  leaving: items.append(key) out properly formatted the outputfile.  This was much more efficient than the iterations I was doing previously.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The csv module is definitely a good start.

I would build a dict for each ID, mapping field names to values. E.g. for ID 1:

```
{'STUFF':'String 1', 'name1':'val1', 'name2':'val2', 'name3':'val3'}
```

You can store these in a list (if your IDs are consecutive integers), or in another dict.

Keep a set of all the field names you've seen. Then use a csv DictWriter to dump out the result in the format you want. Iterate over your list (using `enumerate`) or dict (using `d.iteritems()`), add the IDs back in to each dict, and send it to writerow.

Comment: Thanks.  Will see what I can come up with